# Java stream: using Collectors to grouBy Map

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I would like to transform:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result =
  dre.getItems().stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(DashboardEntity::getElementNumber,
      Collectors.mapping(DashboardEntity::getTotalElement , Collectors.toList())
    )
  );
```

into (naive):

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> result =
  dre.getItems().stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(DashboardEntity::getElementNumber,
      Collectors.mapping(DashboardEntity::getTotalElement + "_" DashboardEntity::getDate, Collectors.toList())
    )
  );
```

But the latter would raise a compile time error:

`Method reference expression is not expected here`

What would be the way to get `result` of type `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>`, where the `Map<String, Integer>` key would contain the `date` (`getDate` call) and the value `totalElement` (`getTotalElement` call) value, knowing that the relation between `date` and `totalElement` is 1..1 ?

Comment: Use a lambda expression. You can't do that with method references, at least not directly.

Comment: What do you want to have as value of the inner map? `totalElement` as in your first snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a lambda; you can't use method references this way.

```
DashboardEntity::getTotalElement + "_" DashboardEntity::getDate
```

should be

```
entity -> entity.getTotalElement() + "_" + entity.getDate()
```